# resolve type mismatch on date

Tags: date, excel, vba

I am trying to run the code below. It runs perfectly fine until I try to add the date parameters. I am getting a type mismatch error. I have tried it with # and ' (single quote) with the same error. The locals window shows the two date variable as variant/string which I think is correct. Any help would be appreciated! Some of this stuff is easy to figure out and some makes my head hurt.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
Dim b_date
Dim e_date
b_date = Format(Range("Beg_Date"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
e_date = Format(Range("End_Date"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=********;Persist Security Info=True;User     ID=SqlLinkServer;Initial Catalog=SPFT;Data Source=001MSDSQL" _
        , _
        "01;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=001MSDSTS02;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"), _
        Destination:=Range("$a$7")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("/*AccountTransactions Current Financials Journal**/ select [Journal Entry], [TRX Date], [Account Number], [Acc" _
        , _
        "ount Description], [Debit Amount], [Credit Amount], [Source Document], [User Who Posted] from AccountTransactions where [TRX Date] >= #" & b_date & "# and [TRX  Date] <= #" & e_date & "# and [segment4] = '" & Range("Segment4").Value & "'  and [segment1] = '" & Range("Segment1").Value & "' and [segment2] = '" & Range("Segment2").Value & "' and [segment3] = '" & Range("Segment3").Value & "' and [Histo" _
        , "ry TRX] = 'No' order by [Journal Entry]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_13"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As it stands both `b_date` and `e_date` are of type `variant`, in this case it looks like you want something that is `string`-type (or converts easily to `string`-type for the interpolation you're doing

Comment: What happens if you try using `CStr` to wrap those variables in the interpolation?

Comment: Adding the CStr still results in the type mismatch error. @Dan Wagner

Comment: Where do you define `Beg_Date` and `End_Date`?

Comment: They are range names that refer to specific cells in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
"...[TRX Date] >= '" & Format(b_date, "yyyy-mm-dd")  & "'... "
```

change your date format to another if this above is not proper (depends on locale).

Comment: I placed that in the line in question with the same results. Would it not be doing the same thing the way I have it in the variable statement itself. @avb

Comment: Could you post your .CommandText value after the code execution?

Comment: +1 great idea @avb -- in general, perhaps it would be easier to assemble that string elsewhere in a piecewise fashion to make it easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: @avb I am not sure I know how. I think the type mismatch prevents the line of code from fully executing and thus it has no value.

Comment: @Dan Wagner  Perhaps. It executes perfectly until I add the date range specifications so I know the date is the issue. I am trying to query a Great Plains database and my research leads me to believe the date should be sent as a string, which I think I am doing but to no avail.

Comment: write Debug.Print "'" & Format(b_date, "yyyy-mm-dd")  & "'" before your .CommandText assignement and post the output

Comment: @DanWagner - I found this the only way to handle date values, if you do not force the format, the output is almost random

Comment: @EricHolder: .CommandText is properly assigned, the error is raised by .Refresh line I suppose